# Flag a question, choices for suggesting another site

Tags: discussion, flagging

Steps: Click "flag" for a question. Choose "should be closed", then "off-topic because" and then "This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network".  I, at least am then shown two options for "another site": "belongs on electronics.meta... " and "belongs on superuser.com".

But say it belongs, IMO, on *neither*, or even specifically, on, say, "Signal Processing"?  How does one indicate that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's off-topic, then close it as off-topic.

If it's a *good* question that is off-topic, then you can flag it using the "Other" line and a moderator can review it for migration.

Comment: OK. I was trying to understand the purpose of the choice: "belongs on another site" on stackexchange, yet not actually being presented with a useful list of these other sites.  Why offer that choice at all?

Comment: @mike65535 Migrating questions haphazardly causes a mess on both sites, so the list of sites you can suggest migration to is restricted. Mods have the full list of sites for migration.

Comment: Understood, but my question stands: Why offer any choice, if the Mods are going to take care of it?

Comment: @mike65535  The options that you get in the "belongs on other site" don't require moderator intervention.  They work by vote.

Comment: I really think that Arduino, Physics and Signal Processing should be on that list, _instead_ of Superuser. But that's another question.

Comment: @pipe By the numbers, DIY probably could be an option (people looking for an electrician, not a EE). Arduino is the next most likely one, but I'm not sure I trust that without a moderator filter.